# linq group by a start time to endtime on DateTime Column

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, group-by, linq-to-objects

Ok this is kinda a messy query and I am only having limited success with it.  I have a list of a Foo class that has a datetime property and other data.  I have a class/row for allmost every minute, with some missing and some entire days missing like a holiday or weekend.  My goal is to group each day for all rows from a start time to an end time.

So on some days my start time may be 9:30am and endtime 3:00pm.  This situation I handle by the following:

```
DateTime sd = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0);
DateTime ed = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0);
var z = Foos.Where(a=> a.FooDate.TimeOfDay >= sd.TimeOfDay &&
    a.FooDate.TimeOfDay < ed.TimeOfDay)
    .GroupBy(a=>a.FooDate.Date);
```

This works fine.  My problem is sometimes I have a starttime of 9pm and a endtime of 6am.  In that case i want the group of foos to go overnight, and if the 9pm is on a friday and there are no rows till the next monday i want the the group to span the weekend.  I would even be happy with a suggestion of a query that would just allways go to the next day.

I hope thats clear and appreciate any ideas.  I tried alot of other ways to do this with loops and creating another list of distinct dates and such but am not happy with it.

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to determine. Are you trying to get the amount of time between entries (Foos)? or are you counting the number of entries between two times?

Comment: Im trying to group the list of foo objects into a time range.  So, on the first day there is data it would group from the start time of that day to the next day there is data endtime. Then on that day start again at the start time and continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In physics, when confronted with a relative problem, they get to choose where zero is.  So do we.

```
// time range expressed as an example in "absolute" terms
DateTime sd = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0);
DateTime ed = new DateTime(2000, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0);

// time range expressed as a zero and range - "relative" terms
TimeSpan zero = sd.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan range = ed.Subtract(sd);

 //the inputs
List<DateTime> myList = new List<DateTime>()
{
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0),  //group1
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0),  //group1
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 2, 9, 0, 0),  //this is filtered
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0),  //group2
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 2, 15, 0, 0),  //group2
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0),   //group2
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 3, 7, 0, 0),  //this is filtered
  new DateTime(2009, 1, 3, 10, 0, 0)   //group3
};

  //at last, the query.
var query = myList
  .Where(d => d.Subtract(zero).TimeOfDay < range)
  .GroupBy(d => d.Subtract(zero).Date);

 //  output the results
foreach (var g in query)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", g.Count());
  foreach (var d in g)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", d);
  }
}
```

Results:

```
2
  1/1/2009 10:00:00 AM
  1/1/2009 5:00:00 PM
3
  1/2/2009 10:00:00 AM
  1/2/2009 3:00:00 PM
  1/3/2009 3:00:00 AM
1
  1/3/2009 10:00:00 AM
```

Comment: WOW!  This is just what Im looking for.  It will work on my regular case too.  Thank you much!

Comment: I was battling to figure this out and this solution worked great. Thanks, for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

This will work but it may not be any prettier than what you're already doing

```
    private List<groupFoo> groupFoos(List<foo> foos)
    {

        //Group by Day into groupFoo
        var z = foos.GroupBy(a => a.FooDate.ToShortDateString()).Select(x => new groupFoo() { Key = x.Key, Start = x.First().FooDate, End = x.Last().FooDate }).ToList();


        //Create new list to hold groups
        var groupedFoos = new List<groupFoo>();

        //add all the good groups to the list
        groupedFoos.AddRange(z.FindAll(zz => zz.Start.CompareTo(zz.End) != 0));

        //Remove all of the good groups from the orignal list
        groupedFoos.ForEach(gf => z.RemoveAt(z.IndexOf(gf)));

        //Sort whats left
        z.Sort((a, b) => { return a.Start.CompareTo(b.Start); });

        while (z.Count > 1)
        {
            //grab the first 2 
            var y = z.Take(2);

            //create a new group foo and add it to the good list
            groupedFoos.Add(y.Aggregate((a, b) => new groupFoo() { Key = a.Key, Start = a.Start, End = b.End }));

            //remove the bad ones
            y.ToList().ForEach(yy => z.RemoveAt(z.IndexOf(yy)));


        }

        return groupedFoos;
    }
```

and groupFoo looks like this

```
public class groupFoo
{

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

}
```

the sample I used

```
        List<foo> foos = new List<foo>();

        foos.Add(new foo() { FooDate = new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0) });
        foos.Add(new foo() { FooDate = new DateTime(2009, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0) });
        foos.Add(new foo() { FooDate = new DateTime(2009, 1, 2, 9, 30, 0) });
        foos.Add(new foo() { FooDate = new DateTime(2009, 1, 3, 6, 0, 0) });
        foos.Add(new foo() { FooDate = new DateTime(2009, 1, 4, 9, 0, 0) });
        foos.Add(new foo() { FooDate = new DateTime(2009, 1, 4, 21, 0, 0) });
```